# "Primarily Opinion Based" on "Best Practice" questions

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

Industry best practice could be described as opinions that have been established and validated by the community.

How then should one ask questions that related to best practice, when these questions may result in "primarily opinion based" answers?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/175248

Comment: Easy... word the question such that it doesn't include useless qualifiers like "best", "practice", "clean", etc.

Answer (score 25):

You don't.  SO isn't the place to ask such a question.  This is exactly why there's a close reason for questions like these.

If you just want to know how to solve a specific programming problem you can ask how to solve that problem, and the votes will tend to reflect which solution(s) the community feels are appropriate solutions that don't violate important practices.

Comment: It's such a shame that SO isn't a place to ask such questions when it has huge number of programmers, each with their own opinions and experiences

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš SO has so many experienced programmers here *because* questions like these aren't allowed.

Comment: I do not follow your logic.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš SO's basic premise as a site is to be a place that is very strict in the types of questions that it allows, not accepting questions that have been shown to not produce quality content; questions such as these.  This is the the core advantage that the site has over pretty much all of it's competition; that it is strict in what content it considers acceptable.  It is the primary reason for its success.

Comment: I disagree. I found lots of value in old questions like what's best book to learn X or Y. I have opened a new feature request to bring that back: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338100/allow-certain-kind-of-opinion-based-questions

Comment: Meanwhile, thousands of developers come to SO looking for answers to their questions but feel alienated and bullied because of the strict rules of what is or isn't allowed and end up leaving with a horrible taste in their mouth and never want to come back (I really wish I could never come back, but I can't think of any place that has as many great developers sharing their expertise all in one place, and I have questions here with good answers I don't want to lose). From what I've seen, it sounds like the ol' folk of SO want the site to be lifeless and boring. Get in, get out, no fun allowed.

Comment: @RTHarston Meanwhile many more developers have found so many of the other Q/A sites out there to be utterly useless at helping them because those sites don't have quality standards and let people ask whatever they want to ask, even if the end result of that is a mess that doesn't actually help people.  That great developers willing to share their expertise in a way that's actually helpful only happens at the place with quality standards is not just some coincidence.  If you want to be entertained, rather than help solving programming problems, there are plenty of places that cater to that.

Comment: @Servy I am totally onboard with the standards of SO. I agree they are what make it so special and better than anywhere else, which is why I come back. But I do think that some of the *people* of SO could be a bit more, well, friendly. That is what I really mean. You can have quality questions and answers without sucking the life out of people. I understand it isn't easy to deal with people that just don't seem to get the point of the site day after day, but there are people who want to learn and get better, and they often get talked down to and bashed by the people who are best able to help.

Comment: @RTHarston So you're just here to have fun and ask low quality questions that are against the site's rules, and you're okay with the site having rules and not allowing those kinds of questions, you just have a problem with anyone who actually enforces those rules when you break them and insult anyone who actually agrees with them.  Your statements ring completely hollow.  Again, if you're looking for a place to just hang out and have fun, and where you have no obligations, there are *lots of places that provide that*, but this isn't one of those places, and isn't trying to be.

Comment: I'm sorry if it is hard to be clear about what I'm trying to say, since this site isn't exactly geared towards conversation (on purpose), so I'll try to sum it up. Yes, I have broken a few rules, on accident, and I've tried to learn from that. Yes, I agree the rules are in place for a good purpose. No, I do not agree with how (some) people enforcing them do their enforcing. It is very off-putting to new users who are still trying to get a hang of the platform. No, I am not here to 'have fun', but I am also not here to be bored to death and yelled out for showing a little bit of humanity.

Comment: @Servy As for insulting anyone who agrees with the rules, if you feel insulted I apologize, I'm only trying to point out what I feel is a problem with the platform: the way some people enforce the rules. Yes, there are some comments of mine out there from when I was still a bit more rebellious as I was still figuring things out, I wish I could take those all back, but unfortunately we humans sometimes say things while in a fit, and the internet never forgets. I still hold, though, that questions shouldn't be closed without some explanation of why the question was bad, or how will people learn?

Comment: @RTHarston It's literally impossible to close a question without providing a reason, not that people are obligated to teach you how to ask an appropriate question in the first place.  (The site exists to help people program, not learn to ask a good question.)  *You* are the one who said you were here to have fun.  *You* are the one accusing people of being bullies because they aren't disregarding all of the rules and just having fun, while also saying that you go into fits and say things you regret.  Consider that it might not be *everyone else* that needs to change in this situation.

Comment: @Servy And *you* are the one misquoting me over and over, so I really can't expect for this conversation to go anywhere productive. I never said I was here to have fun. But whatever, I don't want to keep arguing, I just wanted to point out another SO user's point of view. If you don't want to see that is okay. Good day to you sir, I'll be on my way.

Comment: @RTHarston I didn't *quote* you at all.  If you want to be technical about it, you claim that you're unwilling to use the site because other people here are boring and not interested in fun.  The logical assumption from that is that you're here to have fun, but if that's a false assumption, then what *did* you mean by saying you aren't interested in using the site due to the community being boring and not interested in fun and focusing solely on solving programming problems?  By all means, set the record straight.