# "Why should I do XYZ?" vs. "What are some benefits of doing XYZ?"

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

A certain question of mine, formulated as "Why should I do XYZ?", was recently closed as primarily opinion-based.

I suspect that if I formulated it as "What are some benefits of doing XYZ?", it would be accepted more favourably. This is supported by abundance of questions phrased like the latter variant.

I see a slight problem with this. These two questions tend to attract identical answers, and therefore should be viewed as identical questions.

Should these formulations be viewed as completely interchangeable, or should the latter variant be preferred? Or perhaps both are equally bad? An answer to [this related, but not identical, question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337031/primarily-opinion-based-on-best-practice-questions) suggests that "best practice" questions should not be allowed (I disagree; I consider best industry practices facts, not opinions).

Note that I am **not** asking about where to ask questions that are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. My question is specifically about questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: List of things questions are usually considered off topic because too broad and they don't have a definitive answer. They're better suited for forums or, hey, look over there--is that a chat? Chats are good for this as well. Also, [why you shouldn't be a best practice zombie](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/1228).

Comment: @Will I don't think the original phrasing ("Why...") is asking for any kind of list. The modified one ("What are...") might, I hate it and I never use it myself.

Comment: The original, not at all, I agree. The new version, yep.

Comment: Actually, "Why should I do XYZ?" could very well devolve into a list. "I do XYZ because doing ABC is dumb", "I do XYZ because the end of the alphabet is where it's at", "I do XYZ because I'm lazy". See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), the bullet "every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”"

Comment: 'Design X has the benefit of using much less RAM', (...and is painfully slow compared with designs that use more RAM).

Answer (score 4):

The first is completely open ended. The second asks for an unconstrained list of subjective “benefits”.

Without (considerable) additional scoping and constraints; I don’t see any of these as good questions for the site.

These are only the questions’ titles, though. It could be that the question body made up for the title’s weaknesses (and provide material to rewrite the title itself).