# Why do people downvote questions from people with only a few reputations?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, welcoming

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Why do we separate ViewModels per Activity/Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61791553/why-do-we-separate-viewmodels-per-activity-fragment)

This is a question I got from a professional website and I couldn't answer the question.

The reason I posted my question here was that, I was quite confident that I would have my question answered by a larger community. Of course, I have my question answered by someone (big thanks), but I don't know why someone also downvoted my question.

As a new person to the site, it's a bit overwhelming to see that some people really did not enjoy my question, and it actually holds me back in from asking further questions here.

Comment: Because users vote on the quality and usefulness of post, not on the user's reputation. It wouldn't be useful if it were the other way around.

Comment: @yivi don't you think there are people who do the other way around?

Comment: Users that vote because of the user's reputation? There might be, but I don't think that's the norm. There could also be users who **upvote** new users, out of "being nice". That seems more plausible for me.

Comment: @Ab I mean we head that about every other week. Whenever we ask for posts from new users that shouldn't have been downvotes ... We see a discrepancy between how these new users see their question vs how we see it ..

Comment: For instance, 'pros and cons' questions aren't really a good fit for the site

Comment: Concerning your referenced question, I can imagine people downvoted it due to the fact, that it is hard to give a precise answer. It is more opinion based and thus contradicts list item four of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "on-topic" help topic. Looking at your badges, I have to assume that you did not even take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You porbably have still to learn how SO works.

Comment: @Patrice It is a type of answer that I was looking for. I definitely understood that I had missed something.

Comment: @Ab then maybe don't make it sound like people are malicious? Ask what you're missing, don't say 'Im being downvoted by evil curators who target me cause I'm new'.... Will give a different feeling to your question

Comment: @Thomas Oh okay! It was more like software development best practice question which I still think is a stack overflow type of question. Software Architectures, Design Patterns etc.. are best-practice types of questions still worth to be asked about.

Comment: @Patrice There has to bee a solution to justify why people downvote questions then. I mean the question I posted here is for sure legit for the site.

Comment: Even if a question is related to software development, some questions raise a degree of opinions that make it unsuitable for the site. You may ask those questions elsewhere. Also, "legit" is not a sufficient condition for a question to be good, it may well have other problems.

Comment: @Ab there is a reason: the question on the main site isn't something we allow. The question here seems to be filled with assumptions that are simply wrong

Comment: In general, it seems like your questions aren't practical enough for stack. I suggest checking what's allowed and what's not :/. Posting too many poorly received questions may end you in a question ban...

Comment: @Patrice Thanks! I'll do more research on this.

Comment: see also: [Why always the beginners?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270171/839601)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have currently three visible (not-deleted) questions on your profile. The problem is: None of these questions are really a good fit for SO.

[Why do we separate ViewModels per Activity/Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61791553/why-do-we-separate-viewmodels-per-activity-fragment)
This question asks about best-practice and is more about opinions than about hard facts. Best-practice questions (and in general opinion based questions) are off-topic on SO. You might want to read one of this meta posts: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296542/are-is-it-a-good-practice-questions-off-topic-or-opinion-based), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337031/primarily-opinion-based-on-best-practice-questions?r=SearchResults&s=2|75.6247)

[How to create a Spectrogram in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61773702/how-to-create-a-spectrogram-in-android) asks to find a off-site library. Questions asking for off-site resource are off-topic on SO. If you would remove the library part, the question is too broad.

[Room database and our old friends SQLite, Content Providers and Cursors. Where do they fit in now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394208/room-database-and-our-old-friends-sqlite-content-providers-and-cursors-where-d) is also too broad. It asks multiple questions at once, asks for opinions and is very open ended. It might be possible to improve this question by focusing on one question. Either "What is the difference between room and ContentProvider" (although you have to present some research in the question) or "How can I share a room database between different applications?".

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to improve my questions.

Answer (score 3):

The stack overflow community try to maintain the quality of the questions and answer. Members should prepare the questions in such a way that is easy to understand and not repeated (do homework before posting question) etc. 
Please go through the stack Overflow documentation about how to compile question and answer.

Please ref https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask